# How to change a snippets of code from Class Component to Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Here is the code of the snippet I want to change to a Functional component, I write almost my code here now please check.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { ListItem, SearchBar, Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { getUsers, contains } from './api/index';

function App(props) {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);   
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    makeRemoteRequest();
  },[query]);

  const makeRemoteRequest = _.debounce(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getUsers(20, query)
      .then((users) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setData(users);
        setFullData(users);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, 250);

  const handleSearch = (text) => {
    const formattedQuery = text.toLowerCase();
    const data = _.filter(fullData, (user) => {
      return contains(user, formattedQuery);
    });
   // I want to change the below code to work on Functioanl component
    //  this.setState({ data, query: text }, () => //this.makeRemoteRequest());
   // New code here.....
          };
```

I implemented it in a different way but not work.

Comment: What are you meant to be doing with `data`?

Comment: searching the data, in setState adding data and assigning query by text the in every user typing I check the characters.

Comment: If its an api call then you might wanna use the useEffect Hook

Comment: @SachinYadav I already called API and set the data, now trying to handle search.

Comment: Where are you making that api call is important, you need to call the makeRemoteRequest() inside useEffect() hook

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make a set of data and text, then call a callback after the set.

There are several ways to obtain this behaviour.

What I would suggest you is to have a state ([useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)) which include data and text and then listen for the changes of this stage through a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

```
export default function App() {
  const [request, setRequest] = useState({data: {}, text: ''});
  const makeRemoteRequest = useCallback(() => console.log({request}),[request]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    //on mount 
    setRequest({data: {obj:'with data'}, text: 'text'})
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    makeRemoteRequest()
  },[request,makeRemoteRequest])
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What you can see here, it's a functional component which is:

- setting a state on mount (read comment)
- define a function makeRemoteRequest every time the state `request` changes through the [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook
- call the function makeRemoteRequest every time the state `request` or the callback `makeRemoteRequest` changes through the useEffect hook

EDIT:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { ListItem, SearchBar, Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { getUsers, contains } from './api/index';

function App(props) {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);   
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    makeRemoteRequest();
  },[query]);

  const makeRemoteRequest = _.debounce(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getUsers(20, query)
      .then((users) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setData(users);
        setFullData(users);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, 250);

  const handleSearch = (text) => {
    const formattedQuery = text.toLowerCase();
    const data = _.filter(fullData, (user) => {
      return contains(user, formattedQuery);
    });
    setData(data);
    setQuery(text);
  }
};
```

Actually what you want is to trigger the function `makeRemoteRequest`, right now that you have to do in order to get it is to make the proper set (which means setQuery), which is going to trigger the useEffect

Comment: Please check, I updated my question and added my code snippets.

Comment: Please check my code, in the comment I said new code here.. Try to change its above for me.

Comment: It is working but when the user types in the search bar then every time it is not rerendering. But after the second try rerenders.

Comment: @SamimHakimi be carefully with what are you putting inside the dependency array, maybe there is something missing in one of them https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like the following.

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState();
const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  makeRemoteRequest();
}, [query])
```

Read more about `useEffect` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)